# Different computation of $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I got introduced to the $\operatorname{Ext^1}$ functor à la Yoneda, namely as isomorphism classes of module extensions, and my only computational tool is the following :

Let $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of $A$-modules, and let $E$ be an $A$-module.

$\implies \ \exists\ \delta: Hom_A(E,N)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(E,L)$ morphism such that the sequence

$$0 \rightarrow Hom_A(E,L)\rightarrow Hom_A(E,M)\rightarrow Hom_A(E,N)\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(E,L)\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(E,M)\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(E,N)\ \ \text{is short exact}$$

I computed $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,  by noticing that the short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0$ induces

\begin{align}
0 \rightarrow &Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\xrightarrow{\delta \ \ } \dots\\
{}\\
\dots\xrightarrow{\delta \ \ }&\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\ \ \ \text{short exact}
\end{align}
But
\begin{align}
&Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=0, \ Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})=0, \ Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\\
{}\\
&\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})=0, \ \operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=0 \ \text{because} \ \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q/Z} \ \text{are injective}
\end{align}
Thus, we get $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ from the exact sequence above.

I was trying to perform the computation starting with $0\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\ n\cdot \ \ } \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow 0$, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't get anywhere? Can you at least apply $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\Bbb Z)$ to that exact sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ It should suffice to note that the morphism $\Ext^1(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z) \rightarrow \Ext^1(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z)$ coming from $\Bbb Z \overset{\cdot n}\rightarrow \Bbb Z$ is the zero morphism, for then the *long* exact sequence above reduces to an exact sequence of the form
$$0=\Hom(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z) \rightarrow \Hom(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z/n) \overset{\delta}\rightarrow \Ext^1(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z) \overset{0}\rightarrow \Ext^1(\Bbb Z/n,\Bbb Z)$$
which means that the connecting morphism $\delta$ is an isomorphism.

I think you can do it by hand, since we map any extension
$$0\rightarrow \Bbb Z \rightarrow E \rightarrow \Bbb Z/n \rightarrow 0$$
to the extension obtained by the pushout $F=(\Bbb Z \oplus E)/(nz,z)$ in
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0&\rightarrow&\Bbb Z&\rightarrow&E&\rightarrow&\Bbb Z/n&\rightarrow&0\\
&&{}_{\cdot n}\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\vert\vert\\
0&\rightarrow&\Bbb Z&\rightarrow&F&\rightarrow&\Bbb Z/n&\rightarrow&0
\end{array}$$
but the latter short exact sequence is split and hence represents zero in $\Ext^1$. You can see this as follows. Let $e\in E$ be an preimage of $[1]\in \Bbb Z/n$. Since $n\cdot e$ maps to $[0]$, it has to lie in the image of $\Bbb Z$, ie. $n\cdot e=z$. But now the element $[(z,e)]\in F$ satisfies $n\cdot[(z,e)]=[(nz,z)]=0$, while mapping to $[1]$, which means we can define a section $\Bbb Z/n \rightarrow F$.